# iconv generating UTF-16 with BOM

Tags: unicode

Inspired by [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8923866/convert-utf8-to-utf16-using-iconv/), can I use the `iconv` command to generate UTF-16 output with a BOM and with specified endianness?

The `iconv` command converts text from one encoding to another.

For example:

```
echo hello | iconv -f ascii -t utf-16
```

generates a UTF-16 representation of `"hello\n"`.

UTF-16 files often, but not always, start with a Byte Order Mark (BOM), which is a 2-byte encoding of the Unicode character `U+FEFF`.  You can determine the endianness of a UTF-16 file with BOM by checking whether the first two bytes are `FE FF` or `FF FE`.

The `iconv` command has several options for generating UTF-16 output:

```
$ iconv --list | grep -i utf-16
UTF-16//
UTF-16BE//
UTF-16LE//
```

This command:

```
echo hello | iconv -f ascii -t utf-16be
```

generates big-endian UTF-16 *with no BOM*; it seems to assume that if you specified the endianness, you don't need to indicate it in the output.  Similarly, `utf-16le` generates little-endian UTF-16 with no BOM.

This:

```
echo hello | iconv -f ascii -t utf-16
```

generates (on my x86 Ubuntu system) little-endian UTF-16 *with* a BOM -- but I've seen a report of a similar command generating big-endian UTF-16 with a BOM, even on a little-endian system.

I can always use `utf-16be` or `utf-16le` and prepend the BOM manually, but I'm looking for a solution that just uses the `iconv` command.

Another workaround, *if* you know what endianness `-t utf-16` generates, is:

```
echo hello | iconv -f ascii -t utf-16 | dd conv=swab 2>/dev/null
```

What I'd *like* to use is something like:

```
iconv -f ascii -t utf-16bebom # big-endian with BOM
iconv -f ascii -t utf-16lebom # little-endian with BOM
```

but `iconv` doesn't support that.

**EDIT :**

Can someone with access to an x86 Mac OSX system post a comment showing the (copy-and-pasted) output of the following command?

```
echo hello | iconv -f ascii -t utf-16 | od -x
```

Comment: A BOM reduces the portability of the data but you can [add it this way](http://stackoverflow.com/q/4364156/477035)

Comment: @RedGrittyBrick: How does it reduce portability (specifically for UtF-16)? I know I can generate the BOM ezplicitly; I'm looking for a way to do so just using `iconv` -- and wondering why `-t utf-16` seems to leave the endianness unpecified.

Comment: I guess iconv assumes current platform byte-ordering if you don't specify it explicitly. On some platforms other than windows, some text processing tools don't expect BOMs and so do the wrong thing. An example might be when concatenating text files, or using file-based templates to construct content. "For the IANA registered charsets UTF-16BE and UTF-16LE, a byte order mark should not be used because the names of these character sets already determine the byte order"

Comment: [This question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8923866/convert-utf8-to-utf16-using-iconv/) shows `iconv -f UTF-8 -t UTF-16`, run on a little-endian system (MacOS), generating big-endian UTF-16 with a BOM, which seems very odd.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

**No**, if you specify the byte ordering, `iconv` does not insert a BOM.

This is from [The Unicode Consortium](http://unicode.org/faq/utf_bom.html#bom10)

> Q: How I should deal with BOMs?
>
> A: Here are some guidelines to follow:
>
> 1. A particular protocol (e.g. Microsoft conventions for .txt files) may
>      require use of the BOM on certain Unicode data streams, such as files.
>      When you need to conform to such a protocol, use a BOM.
> 2. Some protocols
>      allow optional BOMs in the case of untagged text. In those cases,
>
>    - Where a text data stream is known to be plain text, but of unknown
>        encoding, BOM can be used as a signature. If there is no BOM, the
>        encoding could be anything.
>    - Where a text data stream is known to be
>        plain Unicode text (but not which endian), then BOM can be used as a
>        signature. If there is no BOM, the text should be interpreted as
>        big-endian.
> 3. Some byte oriented protocols expect ASCII characters at
>      the beginning of a file. If UTF-8 is used with these protocols, use of
>      the BOM as encoding form signature should be avoided.
> 4. Where the
>      precise type of the data stream is known (e.g. Unicode big-endian or
>      Unicode little-endian), the BOM should not be used. In particular,
>      *whenever a data stream is declared to be UTF-16BE, UTF-16LE, UTF-32BE* 
>      *or UTF-32LE a BOM **must not** be used.*

(my emphasis)

I expect `iconv` is attempting to be faithful to the last of these guidelines.

---

Update.

### A digression

In my opinion:

1. An option to specify a BOM would certainly be a useful additional feature for iconv.
2. A UTF-16LE file without a BOM *is* usable in Windows, albeit with additional effort sometimes. For example Notepad's File Open dialogue allows you to select "Unicode" which is Microsoft's name for "UTF-16LE" and (unsurprisingly) seems to work on files without a BOM.
3. I can open a UTF-16LE test file (without BOM) or a UTF-8 test file (without BOM) in Windows Notepad (XP) in the usual way e.g. by double-clicking the file's name in explorer. That seems usable to me. I am aware that sometimes Windows will guess the encoding incorrectly - In which case you have to tell Notepad the encoding when opening the file. This inconvenience means including a BOM is preferable for text files intended for use on Windows.
4. If a specific application will not work with anything other than a UTF-16LE file with BOM, then I would agree that a UTF-16LE file without BOM is not usable for that specific application.
5. I suspect that *if* you can make everything work with UTF-8 (without BOM), that is the best solution in the long term.

However the answer to the question "**can I use the iconv command to generate UTF-16 output with a BOM and with specified endianness**"  is currently "**No**".

Comment: And what about the first guideline, A.1?  If f I want to generate a Unicode text file that's usable on an x86 Windows system, it should be a little-endian UTF16 file *with a BOM*.

Comment: @KeithThompson: Systems should accept *both* UTF16LE and UTF16BE. At least Windows Notepad accepts both, when it comes to `.txt`'s - as long as the file has a BOM.

Comment: @KeithThompson: I agree that guideline 1 should take priority, however iconv doesn't provide a way for you to specify a BOM. The answer to your original question is simply "No".

Comment: Not the answer I was hoping for, but an answer, and a thorough one!

Comment: This answer helped me - helped me learn why I was screwed.  The standard Windows program to export/import from the registry, `C:\Windows\System32\reg.exe` exports UTF-16 LE WITH BOM and will _only read UTF-16 LE WITH BOM_ - will not read UTF-16 LE _without_ BOM and _will not_ read UTF-16 BE _with BOM_ - in other words, it demands the BOM when reading but _it damn well better be the right one!_ (Fortunately, it reads UTF-8.)

Answer (score 4):

If you want to add the BOM to a file you can add it manually:

#### For UTF-8 BOM(EF BB BF)

```bsh
file='main.cpp'
printf '\xEF\xBB\xBF' > $file.utf8
iconv -f ASCII -t UTF-8 $file >> $file.utf8
mv -v $file.utf8 "converted-$file"
```

#### For UTF-16BE BOM(FE FF)

```bsh
file='main.cpp'
printf '\xFE\xFF' > $file.utf16be
iconv -f ASCII -t UTF-16BE $file >> $file.utf16be
mv -v $file.utf16be "converted-$file"
```

#### For UTF-16LE BOM(FF FE)

```bsh
file='main.cpp'
printf '\xFF\xFE' > $file.utf16le
iconv -f ASCII -t UTF-16LE $file >> $file.utf16le
mv -v $file.utf16le "converted-$file"
```

##### Note:

Probably you notice that the BOM in each case is different. You can find [more information here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Byte_order_mark#Byte_order_marks_by_encoding):

Comment: I'd use `printf` rather than `echo -ne`. Various implementations of `echo` handle options differently (or not at all). `printf` is almost universally available and more consistent. For example, `printf '\xEF\xBB\xBF'` for the UTF-8 BOM.

Comment: Not what I asked, but useful information.